# Dependencies on scoped package vs yarn

Tags: npm, yarnpkg, npmjs

I've created scoped package `@scope/eslint-config` with content

```
{
  "name": "@scope/eslint-config",
  "version": "1.0.3",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "8.2.5",
    "eslint": "5.1.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "17.0.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "2.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-css-modules": "2.7.5",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.50.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.13.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "2.6.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.10.0",
    "eslint-plugin-require-jsdoc-except": "1.1.0"
  }
}
```

and in my project added it as `"@scoped/eslint-config": "1.0.2",`

However after running `yarn install` I see only that package without any dependency. But it works with npm

I've tried both `yarn` `v1.8.0`, `v1.7.0` and `v1.6.0`

Have you met the troubles? Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

In npm it works due to the flattern structure.

For yarn you need to say `--flat` but it causes other troubles

https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/5501

https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/3458